# JS for string replacement in a page

Tags: javascript, php, html, wordpress

I have the following HTML appearing in my code

```
<div id="optinforms-form1-name-field-container"> <input id="optinforms-form1-name-field" name="FNAME" placeholder="Vaše meno" style="font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; font-size:12px; color:#666666" type="text"></div>
```

I want to have a js which can first check the current page and if the desired page is visited then it replaces the string "Vaše meno" with "Your Name" in the above code. I have tried the following code but as I am new in js I am not able to make it working. I am working on wordpress framework.

```
var sPath = window.location.pathname;
var sPage = sPath.substring(sPath.lastIndexOf('/') + 1);
if(sPage == "index.php"){      
$("optinforms-form1-name-field").each(function() {
var text = $(this).text();
text = text.replace("Vaše meno", "Your Name");
$(this).text(text);});}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ID selectors start with "#", and you should be replacing the value of the placeholder, not the text. In jQuery:

```
if (/index\.php$/i.test(window.location.pathname)) {
  $('#optinforms-form1-name-field')[0].placeholder = 'Your name';

  // or
  //   $('#optinforms-form1-name-field').prop('placeholder','Your name');
}
```

or in plain JS:

```
if (/index\.php$/i.test(window.location.pathname)) {
  document.getElementById('optinforms-form1-name-field').placeholder = 'Your name';
}
```